# How many paths (seen as subgraphs) of length $l$ are there in a given directed graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

This question is similar to the one answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93123/62603) but it's different for I'm defining paths as subgraphs, not sequences of vertices.

Consider the definitions below.

**Definition 1**. We call $G$ a *directed graph* if $G = (V, E)$, with $E \subseteq V\times V$.

**Definition 2**. A *directed subgraph* of a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ is a directed graph $G' = (V', E')$ such that $V'\subseteq V $ and $E'\subseteq E$.

**Definition 3 (!)**. A *path* in a directed graph $G$ is a directed subgraph P = (V', E') of G of the form $V' = \{i_0, i_1, ..., i_k\}$, $E' = \{(i_0, i_1), (i_1, i_2), ..., (i_{k-1}, i_k)\}$ with $k\geq 0$. Also, the *length* of P is defined as $l(P) = |E'|$.

(Note that if $i_0$ is a vertex of $G$, then $(\{i_0\}, \emptyset)$ is a path of length 0 in $G$.)

**Question(s)**. Let $G = (V, E)$ (with $|V| < \infty$) be a directed graph and $l$ be a positive integer. How many paths of length $l$ are there in $G$? Is there any algorithm to compute this number?

Comment: You seem to be trying to make a technical distinction between your definition of path and the sequence-of-vertices definition, but I think things need to be a bit more precise to make this distinction. (1) In Definition 2, do you require $E' \subseteq V' \times V'$? (2) In Definition 3, must every point in $V'$ appear in some element of $E'$? (3) May a point $V'$ appear in $E"$ more than once; may an edge $(i,j)$ appear in $E'$ more than once? (As $E'$ appears to be a set of ordered pairs, I assume not.) (4) What are the restrictions, exactly, on $E'$ in Definition 3?

Comment: @usul (1) I require $G'$ to be a directed graph, so yes.
(2) No, not if $k = 0$.
(3) Yes, and yes. For instance, if $G = (\{1, 2\}, \{1, 2\}^2)$, then $P = (\{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2\}, \{(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2)\})$ is a path with $k = 5$ and $l(P) = 2$. Note that $P$ can also be written as $P = (\{1, 2, 1\}, \{(1, 2), (2, 1)\})$, where $k = 2 = l(P)$.
However, one can find a path P such that it cannot be written as $P = (\{j_0, j_1, ..., j_{l(P)}\}, \{(j_0, j_1), (j_1, j_2), ..., (j_{l(P)-1}, j_{l(P)})\})$ and this, I think, makes the task of counting these guys hard.

Comment: (4) I'll write it more explicitly. Let $G$ be a directed graph. A directed subgraph P = (V', E') of G is a path in G iff there exist $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$ and $i_0, i_1, ..., i_k$ such that $V' = \{i_0, i_1, ..., i_k\}$ and $E' = \{(i_0, i_1), (i_1, i_2), ..., (i_{k-1}, i_k)\}$.

Comment: Note that the complexity must depends on $l$, since I can reduce the subset sum problem to this problem. If $O((V+E) \times l)$ is sufficient, then dynamic programming suffice.